# Polar coordinate identity $R_{\theta} (1,0) = (cos\theta, sin\theta)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Show that: 
$$R_{\theta} (1,0) = (cos\theta,  sin\theta) $$

$$R_{\theta} (0,1) = (-sin\theta,  cos\theta) $$

Given that $R_{\theta}(v)$ is the result of rotating $v$ around the origin through an angle of $\theta$

I know that it is supposed to be a simple identity, but I am not sure how to show this.  I thought about using the unit circle but that didn't produce anything worthwhile for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the rotation matrix
$$ \mathbf{R}_\theta = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && -\sin \theta \\ \sin\theta && \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}
$$
We have
$$ R_\theta(0,1)  = \mathbf{R}_\theta \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Is there a way to show it without linear algebra?

Comment: @dc3rd Then you need to give a definition of rotation.